# Is WFS 2.0 fully backwards compatible with prior versions?

Tags: wfs

My team has inherited some code that claims to have been written against WFS 2.0 but we need to work with servers that support earlier versions.  Does anyone know whether WFS 2.0 is backward compatible with prior versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not. There are a lot of differences between 2.0 and 1.0, but one of the biggest is the fact that the axis order was switched.

Geoserver has a good breakdown of the changes [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/basics.html).

Comment: By the way, a small but potentially important point here for anyone else coming across this:
According to the Geoserver link posted above, the axis order was switched in the transition from 1.0 to 1.1.  The link says that 1.1 and 2.0 both use the same axis ordering

Comment: Edited into original.